# Beautiful Soup with Python - Return all checkboxes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have several websites with which I need to interact with the checkboxes.

Some of the html looks like this:

```
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <span>Red</span>
    </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
      <span>Yellow</span>
```

And some has an attribute "value." I need a way to return the state and to interact with a checkbox in both situation. But the below code doesn't work because it looks for the attribute value. Is there a way to handle checkboxes in general?

```
def GetCheckboxes(website):
    checkboxes = website.find('input', {"type": "checkbox"})["value"]
    return checkboxes

def GetWebsite(url):
    result = requests.get(url)
    src = result.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
    return soup

website = GetWebsite('https://materializecss.com/checkboxes.html')
print (GetCheckboxes(website))
```

Comment: Your request appears to be blocked by the website: `str(website)` is `<html><head><title>Not Acceptable!</title></head><body><h1>Not Acceptable!</h1><p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource could not be found on this server. This error was generated by Mod_Security.</p></body></html`. You probably need to include a fake User-Agent.

Comment: Thank you, I am updating the original post with one that isn't blocking it. Sorry.

Comment: The returned don't have value attribute. Some have checked attribute. You can't interact with them as you are using requests.

Comment: You can do a more generic select('[type=checkbox]') then check the attrs of each returned element

Comment: @QHarr no need for CSS selectors, you can do that with just find and type=checkbox is only standardized for <input> anyways.

Comment: If you want to actually interact with the page, there's no way to do that with just requests + bs4 and you instead need an actual headless browser with selenium or similar.

Comment: most modern parsers are optimized for selecting by css so it may be quicker. Also, I am using select to return a list rather than repeatedly parse to retrieve a checkbox at a time.